# What happens if a goal is deflected by the referee?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

What happens in football if a player shoots the ball and the ball goes in the goal after deflecting off the referee? As far as I know it is given as a goal, but are there any other consequences?

Comment: I think the question is quite clear ("Is it a goal even if the ball hits the referee first") and the answers are good.

Answer (score 8):

According to [*old* FIFA Law 9: The ball in and out play](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/afdeveloping/refereeing/law_9_the_ball_in_and_out_play_en_47392.pdf):

> If, when the ball is in play, it touches the referee or an assistant
>   referee who is temporary on the field of play, play continues because
>   **the referee and the assistant referees are part of the match**. (emphasis mine)

If a ball is deflected bouncing off a referee and goes into the goal, it's a goal in the same way a goal is scored when a ball is bounced off a goalpost  or crossbar and goes into the goal.

According to [Law 9, 2. **Ball in play** of the new IFAB Laws](http://theifab.com/#!/laws/the-ball-in-and-out-of-play/chapters/ball-in-play):

> The ball is in play at all other times, including when it rebounds off
>   a **match official**, goalpost, crossbar or corner flagpost and remains in
>   the field of play.

It happens very rarely, especially in a professional football game, because referees are trained well enough to be in a position where there is a very little chance of a ball touching them. Even if it happens, the game will go on.

Answer (score 4):

[Here is an instance of a referee "scoring" a goal.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zb29qyqeEH0) There was much protest from the defending side but the goal stood.

The referee in that match was [José de Assis Aragão](http://worldreferee.com/site/copy.php?linkID=4127&linkType=referee&contextType=dyk).

> In the 1983 championship José de Assis Aragão refereed a Santos versus Palmeiras match in the Morumbi stadium. Santos lead by 2-1, but in the second minute of extra time there was a scrimmage in the Santos penalty box, the ball cannoned between legs and by accident the last leg it hit before ending up in the goal was the referee's. **Aragão validated the goal correctly despite a lot of predictable complaints by the Santos side**.

So the referee did the right thing in awarding the goal.