# Are there any goals scored by a referee?

Tags: football, trivia

Are there any goals scored by a referee in a football match, meaning that a shot was rebounded from a referee and hit the target?

I know about [this goal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zb29qyqeEH0) scored in the 80's in Brazilian league from [this post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/14447/12991), but I am looking for goals that were scored more recently and also probably in the matches that had high importance.

Comment: Here is another one I found: [Palmeiras vs Santos in Sao Paulo - FIFA Ref. J. Assis de Aragao. Ina](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zb29qyqeEH0) and [Commentaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsuI-sUSk7Y)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure about the word high importance but only incident I have found so far in a football is, a referee [Brian Savill](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/1760290.stm) intentionally scored for a team losing 18-1 which final result was [20-2](https://www.questia.com/newspaper/1G1-81772757/brian-savill-resigned-after-the-fa-frowned-on-him).

> As the ball came off a player's head, he volleyed it into the back of the net.

Another incident of referee scoring goal is from Turkey 1986 for [Ankaragucu against Besiktas](http://www.mackolik.com/Mac/331851/Ankaragucu-Besiktas) resulting in [A.Gücü 1-0 BJK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJARR76lylE&feature=youtu.be&t=18s).

Not a goal but assist in UEFA Cup 1995/1996 [Bordeaux vs. AC Milan](http://www.footballdatabase.eu/football.coupe.bordeaux.ac-milan.13492.en.html), [Video](https://youtu.be/T90u5cS0sv0?t=1m43s)

There hasn't been much goal from referee and it may have something to do with positioning of referee also. The video you linked shows referee staying in post for corner but now the referee don't stay near the post for corner. [Source](https://www.fifa.com/mm/document/afdeveloping/refereeing/law_5_the_referee_en_47411.pdf)

[image: Ref positioning]

---